# how to concat to columns to one in spark data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to merge 2 columns of a data frame in spark into one in python?
I found this in web but I get error:

```
df4.select(concat(col("originaltitle"),lit(','),
    col("title"),lit(','),col("lname")).as("FullName")).show(false)
```

Error:

> File "", line 2
> col("title"),lit(','),col("lname")).as("FullName"))
>
> ```
>                                     ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from fixing syntax errors (use `alias` instead of `as`), you can also use `concat_ws`, which stands for concatenating with separator. This saves you from specifying comma for so many times.

```
df4.select(
    concat_ws(
        ',',
        col("originaltitle"),
        col("title"),
        col("lname")
    ).alias("FullName")
).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: How about if I have two different columns from two different data frame?

Comment: @elham then you need to join the two dataframes into one dataframe first.

Comment: but they don't have the same size

Comment: @elham you can join dataframes regardless of their size. You just need a key to join on.

Comment: But one of them is repeated a lot, and the frequency of my data is important

Comment: @elham please open another question and provide enough details. It's hard to explain here.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, you have an invalid syntax because of the `as` keyword.
In Pyspark you should be using `alias` for aliases instead of `as`:

```
df4.select(
  concat(col("originaltitle"),lit(','), col("title"),lit(','), col("lname")
        ).alias("FullName")
).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: How about if I have two different columns from two different data frame?